# What's the best estimator for expectation if we can draw samples iid *and* we know the likelihood of each sample we receive

Tags: estimation, expected-value, asymptotics, estimators

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$ is a sequence of random variables on a set $S$, drawn independently according to the pdf $p : S \to [0,1]$.

Part I:

Given some $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$, I want to estimate $\mathbb{E}_p[f]$.

Given that I have access to the function $p$ in addition to the samples $X_i$, what is the best way to make this estimate?

To clarify, the set $S$ is too large to compute the expectation directly. $S$ is a big set of combinatorial gadgets (and in my case even computing the size of $S$ is $NP$-hard). I have access to an oracle that can sample from $S$, and that oracle returns an element $x$ according to $p$, and also $p(x)$.

Of course, I can compute $S_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n f(X_i)$, and this estimator has lots of nice properties.

However, I think that I should also be able to use $p$ to weight the samples.

So, instead perhaps I should compute $E_n(f) = \frac{1}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n p(X_i)} \sum_{i = 1}^n f(X_i)p(X_i)$. (For this I only need a function that is proportional to $p$. This is also the same as $S_n$ for the uniform distribution.)

My more specific questions are:

1) Is it true that $\mathbb{E}(E_n(f)) = \mathbb{E}_p(f)$, $E_n \to \mathbb{E}_p(f)$ a.s., $Var_p(E_n(f)) \to 0$ "fast", etc?

Update: I've observed that, $\frac{1}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n p(X_i)} \sum_{i = 1}^n f(X_i)p(X_i) = \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n p(X_i)} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n f(X_i)p(X_i) \to \frac{ \mathbb{E}[ f(X) p(X) ]}{E[p(X)]}$ $a.s.$. This suggests that this estimator isn't consistent unless $P(X)$ and $f(X)$ happen to be uncorrelated. (Which is true if $X$ is the uniform distribution, since in that case $p(X)$ is constant...)

So I no longer think this is a good estimator. Let me update my questions:

**<s>2) If so, is this is the best possible estimator given this information? For example, maybe $E_n$ is unbiased, and the variance decays at a faster rate than $S_n$? If not, what is a better thing to do?</s>

3) Does $E_n$ have a name? What is a good reference where I can read about the properties it has?

**2) What is a good estimator that uses this extra information I have access to?**

**<s>Part II:</s>

I'm also interested in constructing the emperical cdf of the distribution of $f(X)$ this way. (Here $X$ is drawn from $p$.)

Instead of defining it by $I_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n 1_{f(X_i) \leq t}$, I want to try $I'_n(t) = \frac{1}{ \sum_{i = 1}^n p(X_i)} \sum_{i = 1}^n 1_{f(X_i) \leq t} p(X_i)$. If $E_n$ is 'better' than $S_n$, then $I'_n$ should be better than $I_n$ for each fixed $t$, since we've set $f = 1_{f(X) \leq t}$.

Questions about this: Is this a good estimator for the cdf? That is, do we have a Glivenko-Cantelli theorem, $\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} | I'_n(t) - F(t)| \to 0$, where $F(t) = \mathbb{P} ( f(X) \leq t)$)?

Alternatively, I'd try to build a histogram of the values by weighting samples with $p(X_i)$ -- i.e. building a table where observing $X_i$ adds $P(X_i)$ to the entry at the value $f(X_i)$, then normalizes the entries by $\sum_{p(X_i)}$. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: If you know $p$ why do you need to estimate? Why not just compute the expectation?

Comment: @Manuel The set is too large to compute it :) $S$ a big set of combinatorial gadgets. I have access to an oracle that can sample from $S$, and that oracle returns an element x according to p, and also $p(x)$.

Comment: You seem to be saying you both know and don't know $p:$ what do you *really* mean by "have access" to it?  If you can use $p$ to weight samples, how is it impossible to use it to compute the expectation?

Comment: @whuber The actual example I have in mind is like this: I want to sample partitions of the nodes a graph $G$ into two sets of nodes whose induced subgraphs are connected. The way I'm doing this is by sampling a spanning tree $T$, and an edge $e \in T$, and deleting $e$ from $T$. This gives me a forest with two components, and the nodes of these components are my partition. This distribution on partitions is $T(A)T(B)cut(A,B) / T(G)$, where $T(A)$ is the number of spanning trees in the subgraph induced by $A$.

Comment: My set $S$ is the set of partitions of $G$ into two connected subgraphs, and my distribution $p$ is $T(A)T(B)cut(A,B) / T(G)$. I'd like to compute the expectation of some statistics over $(S,p)$, but it is impossible to enumerate $S$. (It's actually $NP$ hard to even count the size of $S$ for general $G$.) T(A) can be computed using Kirkoffs matrix-tree theorem.

Comment: @whuber I'm thinking that this isn't a good estimator, see my edit after 1).